# Aspx page deployment on IIS V7 Postback redirect to another page doesn't work

Tags: asp.net

I Have 2 Pages of ASP V4.5 which are Login.aspx as a starting page and contentMainpage.aspx.
It's working when I've tested on debug mode in visual studio 2012, but when I try to deploy it on IIS the button log in is not responding redirect to another page.
The problem can be on web configuration
I try to google it for 2 days and can not get the solution right. 
Please help.
here the code bellow:

```
Imports PurchaseOrderList.Class1
Public Class Login
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim abmPO As New ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Session("LoginName") = ""
    End Sub
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            If IsPostBack Then
                Dim LoginAutentif As New PurchaseOrderList.Class1
                If (LoginAutentif.ValidatePassword(Trim(TxtLoginName.Text), Trim(TxtPassW.Text))) = 0 Then
                    LblErrorMessage.Visible = True
                    LblErrorMessage.Text = "Invalid User Name or User Password"
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    If (Response.IsClientConnected) Then
                        Response.Redirect("~/PurchaseOrderHeaders.aspx", False)
                        Session("LoginName") = TxtLoginName.Text
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub   
End Class
```

[image: Web Config]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to "return Response.Redirect". I had this problem in MVC5.

Comment: i have the respond redirect already and works only debuging mode. Soon as i deploy on IIS and it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is most likely to do with this line:

```
If (Response.IsClientConnected) Then
```

Quick google suggests there may be a few issues with IIS7/7.5 and using this property. Also I don't think it's really necessary here, it would make more sense being used in a long running routine to detect a client disconnect or timeout.

Try changing you button click to the following and see how you go.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        If IsPostBack Then
            Dim LoginAutentif As New PurchaseOrderList.Class1
            If (LoginAutentif.ValidatePassword(Trim(TxtLoginName.Text), Trim(TxtPassW.Text))) = 0 Then
                LblErrorMessage.Visible = True
                LblErrorMessage.Text = "Invalid User Name or User Password"
                Exit Sub
            Else
                Session("LoginName") = TxtLoginName.Text
                Response.Redirect("~/PurchaseOrderHeaders.aspx", True)
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: That sounds like an entirely different error. I would suggest investigating that then, as perhaps that's the actual issue.

Comment: Actually I finally get it working. I'm not suppose to import the DLL on asp web application, when I move the DLL on web service then it work. Actually the dll is looking for the component located on desktop. Thanks everyone